# Two one-dimentional arrays and search

Tags: php

I have two one-dimentional arrays:

```
$table1 = (9001, 9002, 9003, 9004, 9005, 9006, 9007);

$table2 = (9001, 9004, 9010);
```

I must to know if any element from $table2 is (or is not) inside $table1.

How to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [array_intersect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php).

```
$array1 = array(9001, 9002, 9003, 9004, 9005, 9006, 9007);
$array2 = array(9001, 9004, 9010);
$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 9001
    [3] => 9004
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`array_intersect`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php).  It returns an array of values that are in both arrays.

```
$match = array_intersect($table1, $table2);
```

Answer (score 2):

[array_intersect](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_intersect.asp)

```
$elements_in_common = array_intersect($table1,$table2);
```